# How to use switch case in dictionary key values with iteration

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, switch-statement, iteration

I am trying to make an application for users to show their actions on timeLine.

My timeline library named StepProgressView hasn't delegate or dataSource. So I can't change text color in iteration with my keys.

There is a titleLabel and subtitleLabel in my timeLine library. If you want how it works you can check the library in this [link](https://github.com/yonat/StepProgressView)

I have title and subTitle array on my project. When I add the titles in my array it gives me timeLine with array items.

I want to change titleLabel text color.

This is my dictionary output when i print it.

```
[17: "17 Kind of long rambling explanation that no one reads in reality", 
    14: "14 Kind of long rambling explanation that no one reads in reality", 
    20: "20 Kind of long rambling explanation that no one reads in reality"
```

I want to use if else statement for colors. If dict value is 17 text color should be red or something.

But when I iterate it fills with last color of key value. This is my problem. I hope its clear.

```
for (key, _) in self.stepDetails {
        progressView.pastTextColor = getColor(key: key)

    }

    func getColor(key: Int) -> UIColor {
        switch key {
        case 0...key:
            return .red
        case key ... key + 10:
            return .blue
        default:
            return .gray
        }
    }
```

It always gives last color because it's in iteration so
What is the best approach in this case ?

Thank you !

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Still unclear. Your code is trying to update the color of a single label but you have multiple colors. Explain how and when you actually wish to apply all of the colors to one label.